# How to configure ODBC Data Source Administrator connection for Teradata 17?

Tags: odbc, database-connection, teradata

I have an instance of Teradata up and running from VMWare Workstation Player on my local machine. I am able to connect to that Teradata database using the default login `DBC` via putty. I have created another login `dbc_test`, using the `dbc_test` also I can connect via putty. I am configuring the same connection details into the `ODBC Database Administrator`. But the connection is not establishing successfully via `ODBC Database Administrator`. I need to set this connection so that the Teradata can connect to the Informatica Cloud.

My Question is I want to know where I am getting it wrong. How to set up the connection successfully via `ODBC Database Administrator`

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct authentication mechanism in your ODBC connection?

Comment: With v17 of the ODBC driver you are no longer permitted to save a password. So if you don't want to have to supply a password at connection time you have to use `tdwallet` and put the "wallet string" key name in the DSN. See the [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/g5M1B6Zfdg6957MmQLY3Tw/BfENGesKs~8ctP~FAdWrlg). This may be a bug or limitation of the "Test" button in the setup dialog. Try saving the DSN with no `Password Wallet String` and using the `tdxodbc` sample test program (in the `Program Files\Teradata\client\17.00\bin` folder) to verify the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from Teradata 17 onwards, TD doesn't allow for testing the connection in ODBC. So in the
`ODBC Data Source Administrator` >
`User DSN` >
`Add` >
`Teradata Database ODBC Driver 17.00`

Click on `Finish`
It will give a pop up like this:
[image]

Here the mandatory fields are Name, Name or IP Address (server IP address) and Username.
Enter the `Name`, `Name or IP Address` and `Username`.
Keep the Name that you have provided here handy.
Then the `OK` button will be enabled. Click on OK.

[image]

Then Open command prompt and go to the location where `txodbc.exe` is present.
Use this command `cd C:\Program Files\Teradata\Client\17.00\bin`

Now let's test the connection using `txodbc`
Enter this command from the command prompt.
`tdxodbc -c SQLDriverConnect -C "DSN=NameOftheConnection;UID=Username;pwd=password;"`

If your connection is successful you should see something like this:
[image]

Here the ODBC connection is being tested by using the utility `txodbc`. TD 17 onwards we can hit test button to test the connection.

To test your whether everything worked or not, enter the command
`Select CURRENT_USER;`
The Teradata database should return the current logged in user name.

Answer (score 1):

I might be out of date with this, but I built a docker image to do just this.

The problem is that you need the Teradata ODBC drivers, rather than the (probably) open ODBC that you're using.

These can be downloaded from [here](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/linux) (with a user) - There is a README but I don't have a user to see it

For reference, this is a [repo](https://github.com/JeremyMarshall/docker-teradata-client) I used originally but that was an older version of the drivers so will need fixing

Comment: I have been using the ODBC driver only. I have it already installed. But still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: did you set the environment variables? `ENV ODBCHOME=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/ ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbc.ini`

Comment: There is also this https://docs.teradata.com/r/xM8ikCYjHVqRVRRtAf6b~g/oPxlRgjADPHlPssWn6HArw - You also might need to check your `odbcinst.ini`  and make sure your ODBC is pointing to it with `$ODBCHOME`